# Swift 2.2 Linux - open file for reading

Tags: linux, swift

(editied to show Swift 1 and Swift 2 code)

I'm trying to read a small text file using Swift 2.2 on Linux (December 22 snapshot).
Mint 14.04 and Ubuntu 15.10 produce identical results.
If there is any way to read from a text file, please answer.

Swift 2 source:

```
let text = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
print(text)
```

error:

```
prefix.swift:18:13: error: type 'String' has no member 'stringWithContentsOfFile'
let text = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
           ^~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

Swift 1 source:

```
import Foundation
let text = NSString(contentsOfFile: "foo.txt", encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: nil)
print(text)
```

error:

```
prefix.swift:14:12: error: argument labels '(contentsOfFile:, encoding:, error:)' do not match any available overloads
let text = NSString(contentsOfFile: "foo.txt", encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: nil)
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prefix.swift:14:12: note: overloads for 'NSString' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (charactersNoCopy: UnsafeMutablePointer<unichar>, length: Int, freeWhenDone: Bool), (format: String, locale: AnyObject?, arguments: CVaListPointer), (bytes: UnsafePointer<Void>, length: Int, encoding: UInt)
var text = NSString(contentsOfFile: "foo.txt", encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: nil)
           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

NSString is not fully implemented yet for the cross platform version of the Foundation framework. You can track the status of the various parts of Foundation here: [Foundation Status](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Status.md)

Comment: Is it possible to read a file into a string with the current code?

Comment: NSData is listed as mostly implemented. You could try NSData(contentsOfFile: String), but then you'd still need NSString to get the bytes of the NSData object into a string.

Comment: I tried using NSData.  Same problem - contentsOfFile is not implemented

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to use Glibc function like this

```
import Glibc

let path = "./sample.txt"
let BUFSIZE = 1024

let fp = fopen(path, "r")
if fp != nil {
  var buf = [CChar](count:BUFSIZE, repeatedValue:CChar(0))
  while fgets(&buf, Int32(BUFSIZE), fp) != nil {
    print(String.fromCString(buf)!, terminator:"")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in Linux Swift 2.2 (January 11, 2016 snapshot with Foundation module)
https://swift.org/download/#older-snapshots

```
import Foundation
...
let path = "./sample.txt"
if let text = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: path as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding).bridge() {  // use .bridge() to convert to String, see https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Issues.md#known-issues
    print(text)
}
```

Comment: It looks like Swift 2.2 does not include Foundation, but it will appear in Swift 3.0.  The following page shows how to compile a pre-release, which involves building Swift from source.  https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/GettingStarted.md

Comment: I installed the latest snapshot, and still see the same error.  swift-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-2016-03-28-a-ubuntu14.04/usr/bin/swift

Comment: swift 2.2 Linux January 11, 2016 snapshot has Foundation module